# How do i call a controller function in ajax?

Tags: magento-1, url, ajax

This is the content of my **`.../template/exportdb/attributes.phtml`** file:

```
<span id = "attributes">Generate</span> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery("#attributes").click(function(){
            jQuery.ajax({

                url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('adminhtml/attributes/ajax'); ?>"

            }).done(function() {
                alert("Hey");
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is my controller file:

```
<?php
class Attin_Exportdb_Adminhtml_AttributesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

    public function IndexAction() {

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Export Attributes"));

        //$this->getLayout()->createBlock('exportdb/adminhtml_attributes');
        //$this->getLayout()->getBlock("exportdb/adminhtml_attributes");

        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template','attributes_exp_db',array('template' => 'exportdb/attributes.phtml'));
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

        $this->renderLayout(); 

    }
    public function AjaxAction(){
        echo "ajax";
    }
}
```

This is the **`config.xml`** content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Attin_Exportdb>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Attin_Exportdb>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <exportdb>
                <class>Attin_Exportdb_Helper</class>
            </exportdb>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <exportdb>
                <class>Attin_Exportdb_Block</class>
            </exportdb>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <attin_exportdb before="Mage_Adminhtml">Attin_Exportdb_Adminhtml</attin_exportdb>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

But the firebug show me the **404**, I don't get to `Attibutes_ajaxAction` function. Why?

The result: [image: result]

Comment: What happens if you access the url directly? I mean via the browser. Im not sure about the _ in the url, try changing the name of the function to ajacAction and call it in the browser to see what happens.

Comment: weird, but it gives me the home page of magento, also I changed the name from Attributes_ajaxAction in AjaxAction

Comment: You are calling an admin controller from the frontend. It is an expected behaviour. See the inheritance of your controller class.

Comment: Also If I use the ajax url like this: url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl("adminhtml/attributes/ajax") ?>' in firebug at HTML it gives me the home page

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you sugested, can you more specific? thx a lot !

Comment: It seems you are extending your class from an admin controller. That means it will have all the properties of an admin controller, including the feature of having to be logged in the Magento admin to access it and it seems you are trying to access your controller from the frontend.

Comment: should I use a block instead ?

Comment: See the answer this question just had.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `$this->getUrl()`, you can try

```
 Mage::getUrl('adminhtml/attributes/Ajax');
```

Please note the method is `Ajax` and not `ajax`. This is because your controller consists of a method `AjaxAction()` and it is not `ajaxAction()`.

Generally this is what `Mage::getUrl('module/controller/method')` looks like. The fields are self explanatory I hope.

### Why your code didnt work?

This is because you are calling `getUrl()` on `$this` which is wrong. `getUrl()` function comes inside `Mage` and it is a static function. So you need to call that method like this `Mage::getUrl()`

Wierd that, `Mage::getUrl()` is not working for you. I will investigate the reason when I get some free time. Now I will answer why `Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl()` worked.

`Mage::helper('adminhtml')` will return admin helper class. More specifically it return the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data` which is located at `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Data.php`. If you look in this file, you can find the method `getUrl()`

```
public static function getUrl($route='', $params=array())
{
    return Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->getUrl($route, $params);
}
```

You can see that in case of admin section, magento uses `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Url` model class in order to generate the url. This is the exact reason why `Mage::getUrl()` didn't work in this case I suspect. This is because `Mage::getUrl()` uses `Mage_Core_Model_Url` model class in order to generate the url, which is I think generally used for frontend url generation.

**So the big point is Magento uses a special model class `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Url` class for processing magento admin urls**

Comment: I'm using this: <?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/attributes/ajax'); ?> and it is working , with ajax not Ajax. Why ?

Comment: and if im not using the helper part Im getting the result (see the image in my post). Can you explain also why? i'm totally confused :)

Comment: try Mage::getUrl() and let me know the result

Comment: I tried also like this: Mage::getUrl('adminhtml/attributes/Ajax'); and im getting the result from the image

Comment: The only way it works for me is by using  Mage::helper('adminhtml')... but don;t ask me why

Comment: see my update. I think you will get an idea

Answer (score 5):

Your request is not reaching your controller because of the way you have defined your controller resource in your `config.xml`.  You are using building a URL with the call:

```
$this->getUrl('attributes/attibutes_ajax'); // also a typo here, missing 'r', underscore should also be '/'
```

but you have defined your controller with:

```
<attin_exportdb before="Mage_Adminhtml">Attin_Exportdb_Adminhtml</attin_exportdb>
```

The problem lies in the fact that you have not declared a new controller with a `frontName`, rather used the `before` syntax to tell Magento to look for a controller match in your module before reverting to `Mage_Adminhtml`.  This is a good way of doing things for admin, but in order to make it work you must target the admin module in your request not your own.  This will trigger the logic to check your module for a match first, then revert to `Mage_Adminhtml`.

So when you are generating the URL you need to be using:

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/attributes/ajax');
```

which will target the admin module, your attributes controller, and the ajax action within that controller. Using the adminhtml helper `getUrl()` method will include the necessary key in the generated URL (otherwise a request to admin will be rejected).

By using:

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('attributes/attributes/ajax');
```

you would have needed to have delcared your own controller rather than using `before` and set a frontName similar to the following in your `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ....
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <exportdb>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Attin_Exportdb</module>
                    <frontName>attributes</frontName>
                </args>
            </exportdb>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    ....
</config>
```

Comment: I used $this->getUrl('adminhtml/attributes/ajax');. Please see the result in the img from my post.

Comment: I don't understand why, but this url: "<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/attributes/ajax'); ?>" is working for me, can you explain me please ?

Comment: Frontend and backend URL's are handled completely differently.  Backend URL's will virtually always require a key to be added into the URL to validate the request, otherwise it will not be routed.  If `$this->getUrl()` does not target a custom block method which in turn calls the adminhtml helper `getUrl()` method then you will need to call this method from the template as it will add the required key into the URL.

Answer (score 5):

**Initiate js in any.phtml file!**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/module/index/getdata"
    type: "POST",
    data: {key: 'value'},
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

**Write controller app/code/local/Package/Module/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
    Package_Module_IndexContoller extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
        public function getdataAction(){
            if($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost("key")){
                echo "data received !";
            }else{
                echo "unable to receive data !";
            }
        }

    }
```